# Adding Additional Slide using HTML causes two slides to merge

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, slide

I'm attempting to add an additional slide to my slideshow and for some reason it seems to merge two slides. I'm not sure exactly what I've done to cause this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

### Slider Source:

```
<!-- BEGIN ASYNC SLIDER -->

    <div id="content-slider">       
        <ul id="async-slider">
            <li class="slide">
                <div class="three-fifth fl-left" style="width: 425px; height: 242px">
                    <h2>Brighter World Lighting - NY</h2>
                    <h3><font size="5"><i>"A not just for profit company!"</i></font></h3>
                    <p>...</a>
                </div>  

                <img class="fl-right" src="img/logolrg.png" alt="image" width="468" height="329" />      

            </li>
          <li class="slide">
            <div class="three-fifth fl-left">


                    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <img class="fl-right" src="img/HOR1.jpg" alt="image" width="450" height="320" /> 
                    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
                    <p>...</a>
              </div>    


            </li>

            <li class="slide">
                <div class="three-fifth fl-left">
                    <h2>Energy Efficient Lighting Products to fit your needs</h2>
                    <h3><font size="5"><i>T8, T12, E27, Outdoor Lighting, etc</font></i></h3>
                    <p>...</a>
                </div>  

                <img class="fl-right" src="img/sliders/async/2Transparent.png" alt="image" width="347" height="305" /> 

            </li>
          <li class="slide">
            <div class="three-fifth fl-left">
                    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
              <img class="fl-right" src="img/REBATE.jpg" alt="image" width="450" height="321" /> 
                    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
                    <p>...</a>
              </div>    



            </li>


            <li class="slide">
                <div class="three-fifth fl-left">
                    <h2>Tax Credits, Rebates, Financing and Grants available for those who qualify</h2>
                    <div>
                      <h3><font size="5"><i>Federal, state and local tax incentives available<br />

                Utility company discounts and rebates
<br />
                      Project financing available to offset costs vs. Savings</font>
                    </div>
                    <h3></a>
              </h3></div>   

                <img class="fl-right" src="img/sliders/async/3.gif" alt="image" />   

            </li>

  <li class="slide">
            <div class="three-fifth fl-left">
                    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
              <img class="fl-right" src="img/REBATE.jpg" alt="image" width="450" height="321" /> 
                    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
                    <p>...</a>
              </div>    



            </li>            
            <li class="slide">          

                <img class="fl-left" src="img/sliders/async/4Transparent.png" alt="image" width="347" height="305" />

                <div class="three-fifth last fl-right">
                    <h2>Allow us to create a comprehensive energy partnership program profile for your business</h2>
                    <h3><font size="5"><i>Calculate your Energy Savings in Real Time!</i></font></h3>
                    <p>...</a>
                </div>  

            </li>

        </ul>   
        <div class="clear"></div><!-- end clearfix -->          
    </div><!-- end content-slider -->       

<!-- END ASYNC SLIDER -->
```

### Screenshot of merged slides:

(you may want to visit the live site to compare proper and improper slides) 
[image]

Comment: live site can be seen at bwl-ny.com

Comment: Are you using any slider plugin? if so, which one? if not, provide the code relevant for slide show. Simply dumping all your HTML won't help. Try to demonstrate the problem with some sample **READABLE** code or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Apologies. Yes - I am using a plugin (AsyncSlider) I posted the code for it above. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to assist :)

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions - they are GREATLY appreciated (I'll be online and ready to respond to any additional questions promptly if need be)

Comment: Is there anything I should remove from my code? I only posted slider relevant material.

Comment: No need to dump the whole source code, i just said mention the slider which you are using in the question if you are using one, so that anybody familiar with it can easily help you..
You might want to read this regarding the HTML: 
[Why Use Css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: I didn't dump the entire page's code - only the slider's source - did I not? (I'll trim it down - but it seems like pretty much everything in the slider should be posted)

Comment: My point was, if it is a plugin that is available on internet, you don't have to post it in SO, if the code is written by you, then it is probably not available in internet so you might want to post it.. that's all...